# ios simulator shows black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Xcode 5 ios simulator stopped working for one of the applications I was developing it works on any other project, there is no build error or anything the simulator opens but there's only a black screen showing.

Comment: Is there any console output in Xcode? Have you tried pressing the pause button in the Xcode debugger?

Comment: no nothing at all, thats why i do not understand whats wrong no errors no output either.

Comment: What happens when you press pause in the debugger? Have you looked in Console.app for any other errors? Have you tried restarting?

Comment: it was working fine around an hour ago and since then i have not added any code just been working on the layout.

Comment: yes i have and even tried it on another mac, no use.

Comment: What happens if you revert to an earlier version of your code?

Comment: try hitting the "home button" in simulator - shortcut is `ctrl-option-h` I believe, check simulator menu

Comment: Nope nothing happened, I had to use a previous save file, I'm going to try add my code back in and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can reset the simulator using the `Reset Content and Settings...`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the simulator get hung for no obvious reasons. Xcode shows in the status display that the app  is running.

If this happens i click the home button of the simulator and then immediately click the app icon again. Then the app appears again and everything is visible wihtout stopping the app or the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases where hitting `Reset Content and Settings...` does not work, it may be due to the background the of the screen being set to `Default`. This was the issue in my case.

If this is the case (for anyone who may be having the same problem I did), just click on empty area of the storyboard screen being displayed and switch the background from `Default` to something else, like `White` for example:

Change `Background` from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I initially made a not needed Referencing outlet of button in a internal View [inside main View] to main View.
Whenever i used to make changes on storyboard, "main View" [not entire screen] displayed black screen.
After removing button reference, it worked properly.

I'm in learning stage, made a attempt to help.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :** `Quit simulator` then clean Xcode (both clean and clean build folder) and then run again.

**Solution 2** (Recommended) : Go to `iOS Simulator` -> `Reset Content and Settings...`

[image: Step 1]

This will pop-up an alert stating `'Are you sure you want to reset the iOS Simulator content and settings?'`

[image: Step 2]

Select `Reset` button. *Note that once you reset simulator content all app installed on simulator will be deleted and it will reset to initial settings.*

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset as described above: (see:  **Reset Content and Settings...**)

If it still didn't help try to scale from the simulator menu;

select **Windows--->scale--> %25 *or* %33 etc.**

Answer (score 0):

I tried what all others recommended in several blogs.What worked in my case is I had to uncheck "hidden" check box in attribute inspector. Once I did that I started seeing the UI when my app builds and runs. I was working to show cells in collection views.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8CVM.png)

[image: View Image]

Answer (score 0):

on my case
i have macbook pro 2015, macos monterey, xcode 14.0
open debug -> graphics quality override and chose low quality [image]